# Is it possible from getting a public void from another C# file?

Tags: c#

I'm quite new to C#, and I'm using it for coding a game on Unity. I have a file named `GameTools.cs` that helps me with commands so that I don't have to do too much. It basically makes my code simpler and shorter. Now with the code...

```cs
//GameTools.cs
public void DoSomething() {
    //some code
    //some more code
}
```

And inside my file `IntroBehavior.cs` has the same `void` as shown above.

```cs
//IntroBehavior.cs
void Start() {
    DoSomething(); //command shown above
}
```

Will this work? Do I have to specify something inside `IntroBehavior` that will be able to run code from `GameTools`?

Comment: See the section on `static`-methods in the C# language documentation. Also, your `CallSomething()` method should be named `DoSomething()`, as a "call" is not the method itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in c# all functions belong to classes. They are either instance methods, or static

Instance methods operate in instances of the class

```
public class User{
      void Login();   <<< === instance method
}
```

used like this

```
 var u1 = new User();
 u1.Login();
```

Static methods dont operate on instances of classes

```
public class User{
       static User CreateUser();  <<<<<= static
       Login();   <<< === instance method
}
```

Here you use them like this

```
  var u2 = User.CreateUser();
```

See that you can mix the 2. If you only want static methods in a class (to be sure ) then do

```
public static class User{
       static CreateUser();  <<<<<= static
       //Login();   <<< not allowed
}
```

So you want

```
static public class GameTools{ 
   public static void CallSomething() {
    //some code
    //some more code
   }
}
```

Now in you other file

```
 void Start() {
    GameTools.CallSomething(); //command shown above
  }
```

Of course that method has to be in a class too.

Comment: So basically this can run in all of my files?

Comment: @TheSoul903 yes